# What is the method for general screen resolution?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have a problem with overlapping views on other test phones.

The way I figured out is to get dpScale and set the size again when the view is drawn.

But I guess that this way has the performance problem.

What is a general development method that changes the size of the view according to the screen resolution?

Comment: I think that the common way is not to do that manually, but use different resources for different conditions.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Are you saying that setting a different dp value for each dpi in a resource folder such as "value"?

Comment: I can't write only 1 word in the comment, so I had to add this. Right.

Comment: Another approach is to use constraints between views and not specify absolute sizes at all.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Henry What is the "use constraints between views"? Could you explain in detail?

Comment: @SelenaLee have a look at RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout in the documentation.

Comment: In Android, we rely on screen **densities**, rather than on screen **resolutions**. That's why we use **dp**s instead of **px**s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you need to define margin/padding in values folder like 360dp, 720dp 
For image use vector asset.

For reference follow :
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: please edit your answer to format only `code` parts as code, not whole answer